# Error:Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:processArmv7DebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, telegram

I used android studio preview beta 4 , I work on Telegram source code ( https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram ) , when I want to connect to Firebase I get this message :

> "Couldnt find keystore in file ({0}) specified for foss build type. {2}"

and get this message :

> No clients were able to be added to your Firebase project for the following reasons : 
>   Firebase: Connect to Firebase failed. Please check your internet connection and try again. If errors persist, you can connect manually at https://console.firebase.google.com

when I connect to Firebase manually and add google-services.json to my app I get this message :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:processArmv7DebugGoogleServices'.
>    No matching client found for package name 'org.telegram.messenger.beta'

build.gradle (Module: TMessengerProj)

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  repositories {
        mavenCentral()
  }

   configurations {
      compile.exclude module: 'support-v4'
   }

 dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.0.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
  compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.3'
  compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6'
  compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
   }

  android {
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig.applicationId = "org.telegram.messenger"

sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['./jni/']

externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path "jni/Android.mk"
    }
}

dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
        storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        v2SigningEnabled false
    }

    release {
        storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
        storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        v2SigningEnabled false
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    foss {
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

defaultConfig.versionCode = 1043

sourceSets.debug {
    manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
}

sourceSets.release {
    manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest.xml'
}

sourceSets.foss {
    manifest.srcFile 'config/foss/AndroidManifest.xml'
}

productFlavors {
    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86"
        }
        versionCode = 2
    }
    armv7 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        versionCode = 1
    }
    x86_SDK23 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86"
        }
        sourceSets.debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        sourceSets.release {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        minSdkVersion 23
        versionCode = 4
    }
    armv7_SDK23 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        sourceSets.debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        sourceSets.release {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        minSdkVersion 23
        versionCode = 3
    }
    fat {
        sourceSets.debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        sourceSets.release {
            manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest_SDK23.xml'
        }
        versionCode = 5
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def abiVersion = variant.productFlavors.get(0).versionCode
    variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + abiVersion
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionName "4.2.1"

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk", 
 "APP_PLATFORM:=android-14"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
 }
 }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (project : Telegram-Master)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you haven't already, make AndroidStudio generate
   a keystore with a key (in my case i've made a V2 type)
   for the project using: Build -> Generate Signed APK.
   Remember the key name, the keystore filename and the 
   passwords you use!
2. AndroidStudio (also java does) provides a keytool inside 
   the jre directory. You must use it to extract the SHA1 
   fingerprint you've just created, this way:
   .....AndroidStudio2.2\system\restart\jre\bin\keytool.exe -exportcert -list -v -alias key_name -keystore the_keystore.jks
   will display something like:

   Certificate fingerprints:
        MD5:  ...
        SHA1: A2:7E:E...
3. You must then go to google's Firebase page(*) and register the project. 
   You'll be asked for the packagename, in case you haven't 
   changed anything it should be: org.telegram.messenger and 
   the SHA1 from your key. In the following steps you'll be
   provided with the google-services.json file to download. 
   Be sure to complete the wizard and make the app created in it.
4. Put the retrieved file into Telegram\TMessagesProj directory.
5. Return to AndroidStudio and try to build the project using 
   the same option before: Build -> Generate Signed APK.

It should work.

PS: I've found sometimes AndroidStudio locks the google-services.json, if that happens, close AndroidStudio.

Firebase page: https://console.firebase.google.com

Other resources: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup